# Read specific character from cell-array of string

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have an cell-array of dimensions `1x6` like this:

```
A = {'25_2.mat','25_3.mat','25_4.mat','25_5.mat','25_6.mat','25_7.mat'};
```

I want to read for example from the `A{1}` , the number after the `'_'` i.e `2` for my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`cellfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), [`strfind`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) and [`str2double`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html)

```
out = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x(strfind(x,'_')+1:strfind(x,'.')-1)),A)
```

**How does it work?**

> This code simply finds the index of character one number after the occurrence of `'_'`. Lets call it as `start_index`. Then finds the character one number lesser than the index of occurrence of `'.'` character. Lets call it as `end_index`. Then retrieves all the characters between `start_index` and `end_index`. Finally converts those characters to numbers using `str2double`.

**Sample Input:**

```
A = {'2545_23.mat','2_3.mat','250_4.mat','25_51.mat','25_6.mat','25_7.mat'};
```

**Output:**

```
>> out

out =

23     3     4    51     6     7
```

Comment: that's fine for 1 to 9 once I have for exemple 25_10.mat | 25_11.mat ...
it returns:
1    1
but I want:
10   11
so finally I want to have with the same function :
2   3   4   5   6   7   8  9  10  11 etc..

Comment: @Devel Edited for that. Can you check it out?

Comment: just one more question please, if i want just only one number example A(1) I mean i want only the "2" how to deal?

Comment: @Devel `out(1)` should do.. Add it after the code. (you can do it for any cell number)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the contents of the cell by using the curly braces`{...}`. Once you have access to the contents, you can use indexes to access the elements of the string as you would do with a normal array. For example:

```
test = {'25_2.mat', '25_3.mat', '25_4.mat', '25_5.mat', '25_6.mat', '25_7.mat'}
character = test{1}(4);
```

If your string length is variable, you can use `strfind` to find the index of the character you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers are **non-negative integers after the `_` sign**: use a regular expression with [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and then convert from string to number:

```
numbers = cellfun(@(x) str2num(x{1}), regexp(A, '(?<=\_)\d+', 'match'));
```